# Mock web service created from retrofit RestAdapter and injected through Dagger2

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit, dagger-2

I am using Retrofit and injecting `RestAdapter` and `WebService` class/interface through Dagger2

In the tests, I am mocking my web service class as `MockWebService200 implements WebService` and I am getting this exception from `Retrofit`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only interface endpoint definitions are supported.
        at retrofit.Utils.validateServiceClass(Utils.java:102)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter.create(RestAdapter.java:193)
```

Here is the interface class for WebService

```
public interface WebService {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/loginByEmail")
void loginByEmail (@Field("emailaddress") String email,
                   @Field("password") String password,
                   @Field("checksum") String checksum,
                   Callback<ServiceModel<User>> callback);
}
```

And, here is my `MockWebService200` class

```
public class MockWebService200 implements WebService {
    @Override
    public void loginByEmail (@Field("emailaddress") String email,
                          @Field("password") String password,
                          @Field("checksum") String checksum,
                          Callback<ServiceModel<User>> callback) {
    ServiceModel<User> userModel = getServiceModel( getUser() );
    callback.success( userModel, null );
    }

    @Override public <T> ServiceModel<T> getServiceModel (T model) {
        // Skipped
    }

    @Override public User getUser () {
    // Skipped
    }
    }
```

`getUser()` and `getServiceModel()` are skipped here.

Here is the code for the `@module` which is providing dependencies

```
@Module
@Singleton
public class ApiModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton RestAdapter provideRestAdapter () {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint( "some_url" )
                .setClient( /*OkHttpClient*/ );

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton WebService provideWebService (RestAdapter restAdapter) {
        return restAdapter.create( MockWebService200.class );
    }
}
```

Questions:

1- How to fix this?

2- Is my approach correct to mock web services through polymorphism and what alternatives I can use here?

Comment: Are you using the `RestAdapter` to instantiate your mocked class? The mocked class does not need to be instantiated by retrofit, since you provide the implementation instead of retrofit.

Comment: Yes I am using `RestAdapter` and providing `MockWebService200.class` in its `builder().create()` as `RestAdapter.builder().create(MockWebService200.class)`
I'll add provider code also in my question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask the `RestAdapter` to implement a class, because the class *is* the implementation. You have to instantiate it separately in your test using a constructor, possibly just the empty one. So instead of injecting it through `Dagger`, you just create your own instance with `new MockWebService200()`. You'll have to implement `getServiceModel()` too, though.

Comment: I have edited my question and provided the code for instantiating `RestAdapter` if I instantiate a new `RestAdapter` lets say `MockedRestAdapter` in my test class how can I force my fragments to use that `MockedRestAdapter`?
Moreover, `getServiceModel()` is skipped here because I felt its out of this question's scope

Comment: The reason you'd mock the `WebService` is because you don't want to test that part of your code; you want it to have guaranteed, predictable behaviour. That is why you implement your `MockWebService200`. This means that you should not use the `RestAdapter` anymore to create it, because you don't want to test that.

So; ditch the `RestAdapter` part of your class. In your test, get a mocked version of your `WebService` using `WebService mockedService = new MockWebService200()`, and work with that instead of an injected `WebService` implementation built by the `RestAdapter`.

Comment: I see, let me try that. Good suggestion.